# Safari Webkit animation (Rotation) not working

Tags: css, animation, safari, webkit

Good afternoon.
Im playing around with webkit animations and somehow I can't get it to work in Safari. The animation worked in IE and Firefox but somehow not in Safari (8.0.2).

Can somebody spot any mistakes ?

I would be really happy if someone can help me out.
Many greetings :)

```
.buttonmit1anikasten:hover{

    width:280px;
    height:274px;
    background-color: green;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 82px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-bottom:0px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    opacity:1.0;
    position:absolute;
    animation-name: spinning;
    -webkit-animation-name: spinning; 
    animation-duration: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes spinning {
  0%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}

    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}

    100%   {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
  }
```

Comment: I assume it would help if you shared some more of the code and also the browser versions and OS you run them on. From my knowledge, out of those browsers only Safari is based on Webkit so it is really odd that it is the only one not working.

Comment: Well my OS is OS X Yosemite and there actually aint so much more code except for the HTMl stuff of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the keyframes definition that is specific for Safari. You have to use `@-webkit-keyframes spinning` as well. You should add the following:

```
@-webkit-keyframes spinning {
    0% {-webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50% {-webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

And adapt your previous `keyframes` removing the `-webkit-` prefix:

```
@keyframes spinning {
    0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
    50% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
    100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Here you can find a JSFiddle I did with some simple (made up) HTML so you can test it there: http://jsfiddle.net/k289yy3x/

Hope I could help.